# How do I convert a matrix to a datatable in R Shiny? (Edited)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do the following, where `num.mat` is supposed to be a matrix populated with numeric values.

```
measurements <<- read.csv(input$Data$datapath, check.names = 
F, row.names = 1)
num.mat <<- suppressWarnings(apply(measurements, 2, 
as.numeric))
DT::datatable(head(num.mat,20),
              options = list(scrollX=TRUE))
```

Doing:

> class(num.mat)

Does indeed return:

> [1] "matrix" "array"

I am not sure why when I try to run the code I get the following error message in my R Shiny app (but it could very well be a different problem):

> cannot coerce class `c("datatables", "htmlwidget")` to a `data.frame`

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Edit: Sorry for not providing more detail in my first post, I have tried to add more context now. I am new to SO and R/RShiny so please tell me if I am still not asking my question correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with matrices of `logical`, `integer`, `numeric`, `complex`, or `character`, so either your matrix is something else, or there is something outside of this line of code that is contributing to the error. I think it would help if you provided a reproducible example, some good references for this include: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Welcome to SO!

Comment: (For instance, does `class(num.mat)` return `[1] "matrix" "array"`? In what bigger context is this code running? Please [edit] your question with more details. Thank you!)

Comment: Please add a MRE. Your error sounds like you try to convert the resulting `datatables` object into a data.frame at some other part of your code which does not work